# What are the most used WordPress localization?

Tags: translation, localization, statistics

I wonder, what languages are most used in WordPress? I want to translate my plugins to these languages and can't find what they are.

Are there an official statistics somewhere?

Thank you!

Comment: (off-topic) Never translate your plugins with automatic translate. Please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### tl;dr

Usually you should be safe by offering your Plugins in English first. If you create a good userbase, you could do your own resarch as to find out which languages are most important to your clients.

Another thing to consider would be, if you want to support latin-signs only or if you want to offer all kinds of language signs.

The big prolbem (for me) is, that I have absolutely no idea if something is correct in another language, where I cannot even read the letters.

#### My unofficial list

After doing a little resarch (to be found below), I would suggest the following priority. My list is based on personal experience, research and common sense (languages a lot of people learn are more commonly supported)

- English (first, nearly every programmer has to have at least basic knowledge of it)
- Spanish
- German
- French
- Italian
- Russian
- Japanese
- Chinese
- Portuguese
- Turkish
- Arabic
- Korean

### Sources

some statistics of [wordpress.com](https://wordpress.com/activity/).

I know, it is wordpress**.com**, but it is the first step to some overview for your most important languages.

[image: wordpress.com usage by language]

[w3tech](http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/content_language/all) has a statistic for content by language

[image]

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_used_on_the_Internet)'s statistics are quite the same:

[image]

However, if you take into account the number of internetusers speaking a specific language, it gets a little different - [internetworldstats.com](http://www.internetworldstats.com/stats7.htm).

[image]

Comment: Thanks @fischi, it makes sense. I see English is the first and the most important language to be a base language. Others are very preferable but it depends on an target audience naturally.

Answer (score 0):

For starts, I would follow @Fischi list, even if I believe is not very precise because of the lack of reliable source (in the sense that they would really reflect the both the actual and potential use of these languages).

Also, remember that these numbers maybe reflect the LACK of localized plugins and maybe an  increased availability of plugins in, let's say, brazilian portuguese (my mother idiom) would bump up brazilian portuguese stats. Something like the old days of browser wars when a lot of sites used to have a low use by non-IE browsers exactly because they were built using IE specific tech.